# Why no seraph crystals?

Tags: borderlands-2

Me and my friend have leveled up to level 51 and fought Pyro Pete on TVHM 3-4 times and he hasn't dropped a single crystal. The quest was on the first time and we just farmed him but nothing was happening. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ultimate Vault Hunter installed, you will get those crystals only if you are on level 72.